# How to take user input from bash script when run as executable without terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, shell-script

I am trying to make a bash script which takes some user input and processes as per the input.

The script is executable, and has a shebang.

The script is somewhat like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read name -p "Enter your name" 
echo $name >> namelist.txt
```

I don't want the user to open the script in Terminal. The script is made executable (chmod +x), and double click on the script will make it run. But it doesn't pause to take input, and the file remains empty.

Answer (score 2):

You either have to have a GUI or a terminal for user input. If the user opens the script in, say Nautilus, there is no stdin, so read returns immediately. One possible solution would be to have the script open up a new terminal and execute itself in it like this:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e $0
```

With x-terminal-emulator, the default terminal-emulator is called. This works with Debian & Ubuntu, I don't know about other distros.
You can call a specific terminal like xterm, konsole or any other terminal, of course.

`$0` is the file path of the script, so this always works.

You also need to make sure it doesn't recursively open more terminals. One way this could work is to check if you can read from stdin, like you do already anyway:

> The return code of the read command is zero, unless an end-of-file
>   character is encountered, if read times out or if an invalid file
>   descriptor is supplied as the argument to the -u option.

So check the return value, if it's != 0, open new terminal like above, otherwise not.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter first value: " first
# Check return value of last command with $?
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
        x-terminal-emulator -e $0
else
        echo $first
        read -p "Enter more: " more
        echo $more
fi
```

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the) if you need to keep the terminal open after the program has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Random hit and trials led me to a solution.

When you double-click an executable file in Nautilus, a pop-up opens which asks you to either "Run" the script (without console), or "Run in Terminal", or "Open" the script in the default text editor.

Choosing, "Run in Terminal would serve the purpose".

Comment: Just be aware that if the user set to run executable text files by default, it will not work.

Comment: Yeah.. got you.